# pytube resolution Parameter not working (Python)

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I tried to write a YouTube video downloader with choosen quality with Python

```
import pytube 
from pytube import YouTube

videoURL = input("Enter Your Video Link : ")
videoRes = input ("Enter Your Quality : ")
try :
    yt= YouTube(videoURL)
    print ("Downloading...")
    stream = yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4', resolution=videoRes).download(output_path="C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop")
    print("Download Successfully !")
except :
    print("Please enter right link ")
```

And this is the Terminal output:

```
Enter Your Video Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ayf8Ij5cak
Enter Your Quality : 144p
Downloading...
Please enter right link
```

Comment: Did you try **not** catching the exception, so that you can find out what kind of exception it is and what it tells you about the problem?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 
AttributeError: 'StreamQuery' object has no attribute 'download'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this error by adding the `first()` method to the stream variable.

```
import pytube 
from pytube import YouTube

videoURL = input("Enter Your Video Link : ")
videoRes = input ("Enter Your Quality : ")
try :
    yt= YouTube(videoURL)
    print ("Downloading...")
    stream = yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4', resolution=videoRes).first().download(output_path="C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop")
    print("Download Successfully !")
except :
    print("Please enter right link ")
```